# Неправильно работает сортировка строк в массиве C

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

Задача - отсортировать двумерный массив символов, он же массив строк. Сортировать необходимо пузырьком. Проблема заключается в том, что при выводе массива одна строка начинает повторяться помногу раз, хотя так явно быть не должно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void GenerateRandomString(char *str, unsigned int max_size) {

    const char *set_of_char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    unsigned int size = 1 + rand() % (max_size + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        str[i] = set_of_char[rand() % strlen(set_of_char)];
    }
    str[size] = '\0';

}


void GenerateRandomStrings(char strings[][100]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        GenerateRandomString(strings[i], 100);
    }
}

void PrintStrings(char strings[][100]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}


void SortStrings(char strings[][100]) {

    int index = 0;
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (100 + 1));
    while (!index) {
        index = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 - 1; i++) {
            if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[i + 1]) > 0) {
                strcpy(buf, strings[i]);
                strcpy(strings[i], strings[i + 1]);
                strcpy(strings[i + 1], buf);
                index = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char strings[200][100];

    GenerateRandomStrings(strings);
    PrintStrings(strings);
    SortStrings(strings);
    PrintStrings(strings);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

После сортировки печатает это:

```
ahtpfivryyetkqaresmeavtsmfnuhdjdurycsbyxogaelkxq
alcuobbhlrljnwwtscrynamjxntimhcvjmkhofggohegktmvnvyrfdkuuyiqtfizomwrcstrbnnonuve
brhaqreufgvzkljsbbhfnoqpbytskkbjpwxubztfcphzfiujkoxkojgwdgos
brhaqreufgvzkljsbbhfnoqpbytskkbjpwxubztfcphzfiujkoxkojgwdgos
brhaqreufgvzkljsbbhfnoqpbytskkbjpwxubztfcphzfiujkoxkojgwdgos
...
```

Думаю, что проблема лежит в strcpy и размерности строк, но не могу ничего другого придумать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы берете строки по 100 символов длиной, и `max_size` у вас тоже 100.

```
unsigned int size = 1 + rand() % (max_size + 1);
```

Какое значение может принимать `size`? в "хреновом" случае - `max_size+1`, т.е. 101. При том, что вы пишете

```
str[size] = '\0';
```

вы явно выходите за рамки допустимого... Потом следующая строка может перезаписать нолик - ну, словом, со всеми вытекающими.

Правильность сортировки не рассматривал - просто удивился, что вы массив из 200 строк делаете, а сортируете только 100. Но если подправить прокол с "захлестом" в другую строку - заменив

```
unsigned int size = 1 + rand() % (max_size + 1);
```

на

```
unsigned int size = 1 + rand() % (max_size - 1);
```

то вроде сортирует (эти 100 строк) верно.

P.S. Но сортировать лучше, обменивая указатели, а не сами массивы символов.

P.P.S. И освобождать память, выделенную через `malloc`, тоже лучше не забывать.

Comment: Да, спасибо вам большое, все теперь работает!